# How to use a button to do some execution on server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a simple website which allows user to download some files from the server side. Those file will not be created up front. That is, there will be a button on the html page. When user click that button, the page will ask server to grab those file from another server and zip it to user.

Currently I am using jquery. I created a popup dialog form which has a download button:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Download": function() {},
        close: function() {}
    }
});
```

When user click the download button, user need to wait for server to generate the file (that is, a blocking call).

I am very new to web development. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to do some server side development for that. Pick a technology for that (PHP, JSP, .net, node.js, Go, Ruby, etc.).

Comment: maybe `buttons: { "Download": function() { <?php // do something server side ?> }`

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it clearer. I am using PHP (codeIgniter) on the server side. My problem is that for the regular button, there is a "submit" option so that I can redirect the task to the back end by specifying the link. But for query, I don't know how to redirect the task without the submit option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to give a file you can simply give location of file in download button like

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Download": function() {window.location='{your file location}'},
        close: function() {}
    }
});
```

If you want to give zip format than you need to use some sever side plugin to convert it into zip.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of server-side functionality to handle that part.  The client-code (JavaScript + jQuery) is disconnected from the server-side code.  It initiates a request, but the server-side code operates entirely in its own application context to handle the request.

There are many server-side platforms from which to choose:

- ASP.NET
- PHP
- Ruby
- Java
- Python
- Node.js
- etc.

Beyond that, each platform has a variety of frameworks which can help with the project.

Some initial considerations include:

- Where will you be hosting this and what is available there?
- What other programming language(s) are you most comfortable with?

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, you need to implement some server-side functionality. A possible solution could be some PHP script like this, for example:

```
<?php
// Code to create the file, I assume it will be an PNG image
$tempFilename = "your_file_name.png";

// The following two lines are important to turn the response into 
// a file download

header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $tempFilename . '"');

// this actually sends the file to the client, there are other
// ways to do this
readfile($tempFilename);
?>
```

You would then need to have some PHP-capable server, like Apache, place the PHP script somewhere and make it accessible via URL.

It is of course possible to do this with other server-side technologies you may want to use. The code will be different, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that I don't know how to submit the form from my client side.

Comment: If you don't have to pass many data to the server, you can do it via Get parameters. Otherwise, you might want to look into AJAX.

Comment: So basically, do it like Sudhanshu Yadav suggested, and append parameters to the URL like this: `/your_url.php?foo=bar&option=2` etc.